# Weird HTML pop-up whenever I have styles in my code or include anything with css / styles

Tags: php, html, css, content-management-system, octobercms

So recently I have made an octoberCMS backend thingy trough my cPanel ( I have one on my localhost ), now I want to add a background image but whenever I do that it gives this weird HTML pop-up that I have no idea what it is, here is the code for the bg

```
{% put styles %}
<style>
    body {
        background: url('{https://arcika.net/themes/sadasasd/assets/img/web-maintenance-cost-singapore.png}}');
    }
</style>
{%endput%}
<body>
<h1> hi </h1>
 </body>
```

I have tried linking the HTML in an asset of css. I put an img to an asset. I tried everything ( updating it , force updating it, refreshing,.. ) but nothing seems to help.

The popup:

[image: The Popup]

Comment: Welcome, what does the popup look like, what does it say? Why do you have `{` and `}}` in your background url?

Comment: The pop-up gives a weird HTML code I will link it now. I will fix that but It is stillt he same

Comment: @MagnusEriksson With one opening `{` and two closing `}}` ? And `https://arcika.net/themes...` doesn't seem to be a variable

Comment: @kerbholz - Ah. I missed that you specifically meant the typo :-) You can echo strings with it as well though, not just variables. It's simply `echo`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson No problem, should have been clearer ;)

Comment: I just need to make a bg image I tried all this is just an example for the problem

Comment: css `background-image: cover;` will give you a big image :)

Comment: Yes but it doesn't fix the problem @dilek_koc

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like (View Source in the browser)?

Comment: Doesn't matter the code, I tried the same code on LocalHost and it works but here it pops up that message and doesn't save. It's due to style and css but Idk what

Answer (score 1):

The answer: Mod_Security disabled a lot of ongoing traffic and thought of it as a threat. To solve this if you are using cPanel then go to mod_sec and whitelist the traffic that matches the error requests in octoberCMS